# Optimized Thread-Safe List in java

Tags: java, multithreading, list, locking

What are the List implementations that are **Thread-Safe** and **performant** ?

By performant I mean, I have a list with **many read** access and a **few write** access.
So I need a List implementation using a ReadWriteLock.

*http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html*

> ReadWriteLock : The read lock may be held simultaneously by multiple
>   reader threads, so long as there are no writers. The write lock is
>   exclusive.

Comment: Take a look at the Collections in [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are the List implementations that are Thread Safe and performant ?

**CopyOnWriteArrayList** and **Vector** are the thread safe implementations of List .

Among these 2 CopyOnWriteArrayList is considered performant in case where in many read access are done with few write operations. Also internally it uses ReentrantLock.

Note:- In case of CopyOnWriteArrayList all mutative operations (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array which is why it should be used only in case of several read access and very few write access. [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you need a few write access and a lot of read access, then I would suggest [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). This is expensive, because every change results in creating new List object. But if your list is not very big and your main focus is on read, then it may be the best solution.